# What can we say about the absolute continuity of the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$?

Tags: probability, measure-theory

If the distribution of $X$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the counting measure, and distribution of $Y$ is absolutely continuous with respect to the Lebesgue measure, what can we say about the joint distribution of $(X,Y)$.

In particular, if $X$ is Poisson distributed with parameter $Y$, and $Y$ is Gamma distributed with parameters $\alpha$ and $\beta$, is it correct to say that the joint distribution of $X$ and $Y$ has the form
\begin{equation}
(X,Y) \sim \frac{\exp(-(1+\beta)Y)  Y^{X+\alpha-1}\beta^\alpha}{\Gamma(\alpha)X!}
\end{equation}

I am more interested in the formalism of the above equation, rather than the actual answer.

Answer (score 0):

The dominating measure of the joint distribution will be the product measure formed from counting measure and Lebesgue measure.